# List the content of the last 5 hidden directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I was asked to list the content of the last 5 hidden directories in the current working directory with a single command. I thought something like this would do the job:

```
ls -a -1 | grep "^\." | tail -n 5 | ls
```

But it just lists the names of the last five directories.. how do I list the content?

Comment: `-1` is not needed when the output is not a tty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ls -a -1 | grep "^\." | tail -n 5 | xargs ls
```

Comment: +1, but `ls -d .* | tail -n 5 | xargs ls` works as well and saves a process.